# Not Getting Mobile Hardware model using 51Degree api

Tags: php, android, mobile, blackberry, 51degrees

I am using 51Degree Api for one of my mobile application, and trying to retrieve mobile resolution and model number but 51degree Api property

```
$_51d["HardwareModel"];
```

not providing any information about mobile model
and also for Blackberry Bold 9790 cell phone it is not giving correct Screen Size..
Using property

```
**
$_51d["ScreenPixelsHeight"];
**

and 

**
$_51d["ScreenPixelsWidth"];
**
```

** for getting Screen Size.
What could be the Problem here can anybody tell me??

Answer (score 0):

As per the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) I state that I work for 51degrees.mobi.

Are you using the Lite or Premium version of 51Degrees.mobi? "HardwareModel" is a property that is only available in our premium data set and would not be accessible if you are using the lite version. For a list of properties available to both versions please see the [property dictionary](http://51degrees.mobi/Products/DeviceData/PropertyDictionary.aspx?CATReferrer=1758).

Please can you define what you mean by not giving correct screen size. The properties that should be returned are:

```
ScreenPixelHeight: 360
ScreenPixelWidth: 480
```

Which is the same as listed on the [BlackBerry website](http://uk.blackberry.com/smartphones/blackberry-bold-9790/where-to-buy.html?CPID=KNC-kw187286_p8&HBX_PK=rim%7C2415f57b-749d-b069-b2f9-00001274e123#/h:/smartphones/blackberry-bold-9790/phone-specifications.html). Can you provide the User Agent you are using? Hope this helps :)